# Sort by joined table attribute

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have two Entities in my Extbase extension. Adress and Category.Every address have one category (Category 1:N Adress):

Every category have a title and a description. Now i want to implement a function im my `AddressRepository` to get all Adresses which was sort by category title.

How can i join both table and sort by joined table title in Extbase?

Can someone give me a hint?

**Update**:

Now i solved my issue with plain SQL statements